# Делаю анимацию.. как определить центр?

Tags: svg, smil

Делаю анимацию вращение формы и она крутится, всё как положено но ось находится где в непонятном месте...

**Что надо сделать что бы g.znak крутился точно в центре сердца ?**

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 150 146" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

 <g transform="translate(-91.152161,-220.51316)" fill="none" stroke="#000">
  <g id="znak"  stroke-width="0.1">
   <path d="m137.29866 241.38105-6.88061 3.787c0.74789 17.70383 14.83325 24.16791 23.13092 24.23324l-3.62699-6.75615 3.69811-6.89838c-4.07845-1.29738-8.09181-2.7488-9.38749-10.63204z"/>
   <path d="m137.36978 239.88759-6.89838 3.66254c2.5313-19.50783 17.08121-22.77823 24.39323-23.18425l3.84034 6.82726-3.84034 7.04062c-7.92084 0.88471-9.39692 5.26021-10.45424 9.45861z"/>
   <path d="m156.50034 220.47256 3.84034 6.82726-3.94701 6.9695c8.11787 1.89453 8.85398 6.18814 9.56527 10.48981l6.82728 3.80478 7.07616-3.80478c-1.57467-20.04817-16.94185-23.68416-23.36204-24.28657z"/>
   <path d="m165.81671 246.32371 7.11174 3.87589 6.86283-3.73365c-2.41716 18.18685-16.04929 22.79311-24.49994 23.18425l-3.80477-6.93394 3.76923-6.9695c4.75174-0.60776 9.08407-2.07834 10.56091-9.42305z"/>
 <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                   attributeType="XML"
                   type="rotate"
                   from="0 125 250"
                   to="360 125 250"
                   dur="3s"
                   repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </g>
  <path id="heard" d="m115.75291 266.21583c6.00669-10.16322 21.06124-15.24936 24.91168-31.07147 0.93683-3.84963-2.03409-8.80426-5.35766-11.57019-13.69952-6.9619-17.94693 2.69878-19.43623 4.82958-5.27315-8.1827-11.41642-10.146-20.142967-3.88722-5.541694 4.32833-4.651824 11.69502-3.028785 15.88916 3.28437 8.48725 15.085042 14.02852 23.053962 25.81014z" stroke-width="0.1"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ничего не считать вручную Вам поможет [`getBBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox):

На сколько сдвинуть символ сердца тоже можно посчитать через  [`getBBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox)

```js
let bb = znak.getBBox();
let center = `${bb.x+bb.width/2} ${bb.y+bb.height/2}`
anim.setAttribute("from", `0 ${center}`)
anim.setAttribute("to", `360 ${center}`)
```

```html
<svg viewBox="81 180 150 150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="90vh">

 <g fill="none" stroke="#000">
  <g id="znak"  stroke-width="0.3">
   <path d="m137.29866 241.38105-6.88061 3.787c0.74789 17.70383 14.83325 24.16791 23.13092 24.23324l-3.62699-6.75615 3.69811-6.89838c-4.07845-1.29738-8.09181-2.7488-9.38749-10.63204z"/>
   <path d="m137.36978 239.88759-6.89838 3.66254c2.5313-19.50783 17.08121-22.77823 24.39323-23.18425l3.84034 6.82726-3.84034 7.04062c-7.92084 0.88471-9.39692 5.26021-10.45424 9.45861z"/>
   <path d="m156.50034 220.47256 3.84034 6.82726-3.94701 6.9695c8.11787 1.89453 8.85398 6.18814 9.56527 10.48981l6.82728 3.80478 7.07616-3.80478c-1.57467-20.04817-16.94185-23.68416-23.36204-24.28657z"/>
   <path d="m165.81671 246.32371 7.11174 3.87589 6.86283-3.73365c-2.41716 18.18685-16.04929 22.79311-24.49994 23.18425l-3.80477-6.93394 3.76923-6.9695c4.75174-0.60776 9.08407-2.07834 10.56091-9.42305z"/>
 <animateTransform id="anim" attributeName="transform"
                   attributeType="XML"
                   type="rotate"
                   dur="3s"
                   repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </g>
  <path transform="scale(3) translate(-64,-160)" id="heard" d="m115.75291 266.21583c6.00669-10.16322 21.06124-15.24936 24.91168-31.07147 0.93683-3.84963-2.03409-8.80426-5.35766-11.57019-13.69952-6.9619-17.94693 2.69878-19.43623 4.82958-5.27315-8.1827-11.41642-10.146-20.142967-3.88722-5.541694 4.32833-4.651824 11.69502-3.028785 15.88916 3.28437 8.48725 15.085042 14.02852 23.053962 25.81014z" stroke-width="0.1"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```